Why can't derivatives jump over 0?
Derivatives follow $nx^{n-1}$ which works for either positive numbers or negative numbers. For example:
With $f_1(x)=X^3$ then $f_1'(x)=3X^2$
With $f_2(x)=X^{-3}$ then $f_2'(x)=-3X^{-4}$
But other than the obvious (0 times anything is 0), why can't derivatives jump over 0?

Well, ..., $x^0 = 1$, isn't really a function that is a power of $x$; it is a function that is constant (and there is an easier rule for the derivative of a constant that agrees with the one you describe).  But perhaps it is of more use to know that the derivative $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x \ \ln(|x|) = x^{-1}$ and the natural logarithm is not a power of $x$ (so the power of $x$ that should land on $x^{-1}$ doesn't).

What about the derivative of $x^{1/2}$, which is $\frac12 x^{-1/2}$ - is this a case of "jumping over 0"? (I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.)

$\frac{dx^0}{dx} = 0x^{-1}$ everywhere except at $x = 0$. Is this a case of "jumping over 0"?

What do you mean by “why can’t derivatives jump over 0”?   This is unclear in several ways: Do you mean $n = 0$, or  $X = 0$, or $f(X) = 0$, or something else? And what do you mean they “can’t jump over” that zero?  Without some clarification, we can’t answer this question for you.

For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ and $f(x)=x^\alpha$ you find
$$f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$
Especially for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$, you find a "jump over $0$" because $\alpha-1 < 0$.

Note that for $\alpha=0$, it holds $f(x)=x^\alpha =1$ with
$$f'(x)=0$$
In this case, the derivative is not a non-trivial multiple of $x^{\alpha-1}=x^{-1}$.
However, there exists an antiderivative for $x^{-1}$: For $f(x)=\ln(|x|)$, it holds
$$f'(x)=x^{-1}$$

Restatement of the Question to Make it Easier to Reference in the Answer

Derivatives follow $nx^{n-1}$ which works for either positive numbers
or negative numbers. For example:
With $f_1(x)=X^3$ then $f_1'(x)=3X^2$
With $f_2(x)=X^{-3}$ then $f_2'(x)=-3X^{-4}$
But other than the obvious (0 times anything is 0), why can't
derivatives jump over 0?

Solution Steps
The proof for:
$$\boxed{
\left(x^n\right)^{'}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=n \, x^{n-1}
}$$
is in my answer to the Math Stack Exchange article "Proof in the Derivative of $x^n\,\,$"
When $x$ is $x\overset{\text{is the constant}}=0$, then $\left(x^n\right)^{'}=0$ for $n\ge 0$.  Smooth continuous functions can be built up as a Taylor Series (from Taylor's Theorem) as $f=\sum_{i\ge 0} a_i x^i$, where it is "an approximation of a
$
{\textstyle k}-$ times differentiable function around a given point by a polynomial of degree
${\textstyle k}$, called the
${\textstyle k}$-th-order Taylor polynomial"
So in a sense as long as there is no discontinuous point at $x=0$, then "jumping over" is just taking a limit of the function at $f\left(x\right) \to f\left(x_0\right)$ and $f\left(x+h\right) \to f\left(x_0+h\right)$.
The problem is when $f\left(0\right)$ is not defined, or when it is not continuous, resulting in a finite (or unbounded infinite) value in the top of the fraction namely $f\left(x=0+h\right)-f\left(x=0\right)$.  In that case, there is no (finite) limit as $\frac1{h}\to \frac1{h\to 0} \to \infty$.

I think this answer is about the value a derivative takes at 0, but I think the question is asking about the forms of the derivatives of polynomials.

Let's return to your examples:

First, you consider $f_1(x) = x^3$. This function is continuous at 0. It's derivative is $3x^2$ which is also continuous at 0. This function has an ordinary derivative at 0.

Second, you consider $f_2(x) = x^{-3}$. This function is not continuous at 0:

coming in from the right, that is: $x \approx 0$ and $x > 0$, it is tending to $\infty$.
coming in from the left, that is $x \approx 0$ and $x < 0$, it is tending to $-\infty$.

Since the function does not have a value at 0, it does not have an ordinary derivative at 0. I won't try to make a mathematically precise version of that statement since I do not know your level, but I encourage you to return to whichever definition of differentiability you have and see that it does not apply to $f_2$ at $x=0$


